# How to "where" based on the last StructType of a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a DataFrame of a StructType list column named 'arr', which can be described by the following json,

```
{
  "otherAttribute": "blabla...",
  "arr": [
     {
        "domain": "books",
        "others": "blabla..."
     }
     {
        "domain": "music",
        "others": "blabla..."
     }
  ]
}
{
  "otherAttribute": "blabla...",
  "arr": [
     {
        "domain": "music",
        "others": "blabla..."
     }
     {
        "domain": "furniture",
        "others": "blabla..."
     }
  ]
}
... ...
```

We want to filter out records such that the last StructType in "arr" has its "domain" attribute being "music". In the above example, we need to keep the firs record but discard the second record. Need help to write such "where" clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is based on this data:

```
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|other_attribute|arr                                           |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
|first          |[[books, ...], [music, ...]]                  |
|second         |[[books, ...], [music, ...], [furniture, ...]]|
|third          |[[football, ...], [soccer, ...]]              |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

`arr` here is an array of structs. 
Each element of `arr` has attributes `domain` and `others` (filled with `...` here).

DataFrame API approach (`F` is `pyspark.sql.functions`):

```py
df.filter(
    F.col("arr")[F.size(F.col("arr")) - 1]["domain"] == "music"
)
```

The SQL way:

```sql
SELECT 
  other_attribute,
  arr
FROM df
WHERE arr[size(arr) - 1]['domain'] = 'music'
```

The output table will look like this:

```
+---------------+----------------------------+
|other_attribute|arr                         |
+---------------+----------------------------+
|first          |[[books, ...], [music, ...]]|
+---------------+----------------------------+
```

Full code (suggesting using PySpark console):

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = T.StructType()\
    .add("other_attribute", T.StringType())\
    .add("arr", T.ArrayType(
        T.StructType()
            .add("domain", T.StringType())
            .add("others", T.StringType())
        )
    )

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["first", [["books", "..."], ["music", "..."]]],
    ["second", [["books", "..."], ["music", "..."], ["furniture", "..."]]],
    ["third", [["football", "..."], ["soccer", "..."]]]
], schema)

filtered = df.filter(
    F.col("arr")[F.size(F.col("arr")) - 1]["domain"] == "music"
)

filtered.show(100, False)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

filtered_with_sql = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
      other_attribute,
      arr
    FROM df
    WHERE arr[size(arr) - 1]['domain'] = 'music'
""")

filtered_with_sql.show(100, False)
```

Comment: This exactly answers my question. Thanks!